# Value of an object will not be changed

Tags: c++, reference

I created a method which should change values in my shop object. Unfortunately the values are not changed.

edit: 18:13

I could create a new shop object and return it, but I thought it should work with passing the object by reference?

To make my question clearer: My only problem is, that the new values are not stored in the object. I did run the debugging and the values are all correctly calculated and as expected.

The problem is in the lines:

```
shop.get_stock().push_back(inventory_bonbon);
```

This line should push a new inventory item to the vector (containing the inventory items), if this inventory item is currently not in stock.

Here I increase the amount of an inventory item, when the item is currently in stock:

```
i_inventory_shop.increase_amount(shop.get_stock()[i], amount);
```

(I have unit-tested the increase_amount() method and it works fine.)

The two lines are called as expected (meaning I find when an item is in stock or not).

---

```
void IRooms::increase_inventory_shop(Shop & shop, Bonbon & bonbon, int amount)
{
    OutputDebugString("I_Game Logic increase_inventory_shop called \n");

    IInventoryItemsBonbons i_inventory_shop;
    bool bonbon_in_shop = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < shop.get_stock().size(); i++)
    {
        OutputDebugString(("I_Game Logic shop vector size \n" + std::to_string(shop.get_stock().size()) + "\n").c_str());
        OutputDebugString(("I_Game Logic bonbon name \n" + bonbon.get_name() + "\n").c_str());
        OutputDebugString(("I_Game Logic bonbon amount \n" + std::to_string(amount) + "\n").c_str());

        if (bonbon.get_name() == shop.get_stock()[i].get_bonbon().get_name())
        {
            bonbon_in_shop = true;
            OutputDebugString("Bonbon found \n");
            i_inventory_shop.increase_amount(shop.get_stock()[i], amount);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bonbon_in_shop == false) {
        OutputDebugString("Bonbon not found \n");
        InventoryItemBonbons inventory_bonbon = i_inventory_shop.create(amount, bonbon);
        shop.get_stock().push_back(inventory_bonbon);
    }
}
```

This method calls: (the method below, I have tested it)

```
void IInventoryItemsBonbons::increase_amount(InventoryItemBonbons & inventoryitem_shop, int amount)
{
    int old_amount = inventoryitem_shop.get_amount();
    int new_amount = old_amount + amount;
    inventoryitem_shop.set_amount(new_amount);
}
```

edit 17:51:

Shop.h

```
std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons> get_stock();
```

Shop.ccp

```
std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons> Shop::get_stock()
{
    return stock_bonbons;
}
```

_____________________________________________________________________________edit: 19:54

I have now introduced local variables and I return the local shop.

```
Shop IRooms::increase_inventory_shop(Shop & shop, Bonbon & bonbon, int amount)
{
    Shop shop_temp = shop; 
    std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons> inventory_items_temp = shop.get_stock();
    IInventoryItemsBonbons i_inventory_shop;
    bool bonbon_in_shop = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < shop_temp.get_stock().size(); i++)
    {
        if (bonbon.get_name() == shop_temp.get_stock()[i].get_bonbon().get_name())
        {
            bonbon_in_shop = true;
            i_inventory_shop.increase_amount(inventory_items_temp[i], amount);
            break;
        }
    }

    if (bonbon_in_shop == false) {
        InventoryItemBonbons inventory_bonbon = i_inventory_shop.create(amount, bonbon);
        inventory_items_temp.push_back(inventory_bonbon);
    }

    shop_temp.set_stock(inventory_items_temp);

    //shop = shop_temp; 
    //return shop;
    return shop_temp;
}
```

The only thing I want to know, why the values of shop won't change. I have tried to copy shop_temp to shop, but even this does not work.

Comment: Instead of checking just the output, why nut actually *run* in a debugger, and step through the code line by line to see what *really* happens, and also *step into* the functions you call, the error might not be in the code you show.

Comment: I would guess that the reason your shop object isn't changed is that you are writing to a local variable `IInventoryItemsBonbons i_inventory_shop;` instead of wherever you thought you were writing to.

Comment: How does `Shop::get_stock()` look?

Comment: I am running the debugger. All the values in my debug messages are as expected. The values are just not changed in my shop object.  The IInventoryItemsBonbons  is an interface, which I use for calling the second method.

Comment: I'd like to help, but it's hopeless if you hide half of the code which might contain the error. In C++, every function can do everything. For all we know, `Bonbon::get_name` might use `memset` to manipulate the memory location of `bonbon_in_shop`.

Comment: the only lines which are not working as expected are:i_inventory_shop.increase_amount(shop.get_stock()[i], amount); and shop.get_stock().push_back(inventory_bonbon); i have unit_tested the rest of my code; i could create a new object and return it - but I guess it should work with passing references or am I wrong?

Comment: You are learning an important thing or two about the value of unit tests, especially how they are not a replacement for code reviews and functional testing. Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to find out how to show us a code example that allows us to identify the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons> get_stock();
```

Since `get_stock` returns by value, not by reference, any changes to the value returned will be lost as soon as that temporary goes out of scope.

```
shop.get_stock().push_back(inventory_bonbon);
```

So this modifies the temporary returned by `get_stock`, which immediately goes out of scope, is destroyed, and the modification is lost.

You probably wanted:

```
std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons>& get_stock();
 ...
std::vector<InventoryItemBonbons>& Shop::get_stock()
{
    return stock_bonbons;
}
```